# skip update columns with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I've got an API up on node using pg-promise for Postgres, this works well but i'm thinking about how to modify the PUT statement to handle NULLS in the input a little better.

The following is the code for the PUT statement:

```
    //UPDATE a single record
function updateRecord(req, res, next) {
    db.none('update generic1 SET string1=$1,' +
                               'string2=$2,' +
                               'string3=$3,' +
                               'string4=$4,' +
                               'string5=$5,' +
                               'string6=$6,' +
                               'integer1=$7,' +
                               'integer2=$8,' +
                               'integer3=$9,' +
                               'date1=$10,' +
                               'date2=$11,' +
                               'date3=$12,' +
                               'currency1=$13,' +
                               'currency2=$14' +
            'WHERE id = $15',
            [req.body.string1,
             req.body.string2,
             req.body.string3,
             req.body.string4,
             req.body.string5,
             req.body.string6,
             parseInt(req.body.integer1),
             parseInt(req.body.integer2),
             parseInt(req.body.integer3),
             req.body.date1,
             req.body.date2,
             req.body.date3,
             parseInt(req.body.currency1),
             parseInt(req.body.currency2),
             parseInt(req.params.id)])
        .then(function(){
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    'status': 'success',
                    'message': 'updated one record'
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return next(err);
        });
}
```

Now this statement works, but it also removes existing values if I pass in NULLS to the next update. For example, if I wanted to just update string1 and date2 for example, i'd have to send the entire json object or all the other values are being set to NULL.

Is there a better way to handle this? Should I be using the PATCH verb instead??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    capSQL: true // capitalize all generated SQL
});

// generic way to skip NULL/undefined values for strings:
function str(col) {
    return {
        name: col,
        skip() {
            const val = this[col];
            return val === null || val === undefined;
        }
    };
}

// generic way to skip NULL/undefined values for integers,
// while parsing the type correctly:
function int(col) {
    return {
        name: col,
        skip() {
            const val = this[col];
            return val === null || val === undefined;
        },
        init() {
            return parseInt(this[col]);
        }
    };
}

// Creating a reusable ColumnSet for all updates:
const csGeneric = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    str('string1'), str('string2'), str('string3'), str('string4'), str('string5'),
    str('string6'), int('integer1'), int('integer2'), int('integer3'),
    str('date1'), str('date2'), str('date3')
], {table: 'generic1'});

// Your new request handler:
async function updateRecord(req, res, next) {

    const update = pgp.helpers.update(req.body, csGeneric) + ' WHERE id = ' +
        parseInt(req.params.id);

    try {
            await db.none(update);
            res.status(200);
    } catch(err) {
        return next(err);
    }
}
```

See the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) namespace ;)

---

Alternatively, you can do your own verification for each column, and then generate an `UPDATE` query accordingly, though it won't be as elegant ;)

**UPDATE**

Please note that the way `init` and `skip` are parameterized changed in version 5.4.0 of the library, see [the release notes](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.5.4.0).

Starting from version 5.4.0, you can simplify the code as this:

```
// generic way to skip NULL/undefined values for strings:
function str(column) {
    return {
        name: column,
        skip: c => c.value === null || c.value === undefined
    };
}

// generic way to skip NULL/undefined values for integers,
// while parsing the type correctly:
function int(column) {
    return {
        name: column,
        skip: c => c.value === null || c.value === undefined,
        init: c => +c.value
    };
}
```

And if you want to skip the properties that were not passed in at all, and thus do not even exist within the object, then instead of this:

```
skip: c => c.value === null || c.value === undefined
```

you can do this:

```
skip: c => !c.exists
```

**UPDATE**

Version 5.6.7 of the library received a further improvement for this - option `emptyUpdate`, which when specified represents the value to be returned by the method, rather than throwing `Cannot generate an UPDATE without any columns`. See [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update) for details.

See also: [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig).

Comment: @adam.sellers see the update about the very latest version ;)

Comment: @adam.sellers another update has been added - option `emptyUpdate` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
function updateFoo(req, res){ 
    let {name, email, password} = req.body; 
    // Ex: req.body = { name: 'foo', password: 'bar' }
    let data = { name, email, password }; // {name: 'foo', email:undefined, password:'bar}
    //Remove ONLY undefined keys from data
    Object.keys(data).forEach( key => { if(data[key] === undefined) delete data[key] });

    let query = 'UPDATE foo SET';

    let i = 1;
    Object.keys(data).forEach( key => { query += ` ${key}=$${index},`; i++; })
    query = query.slice(0, -1) // Remove exceeding comma
    query += ` WHERE id=$${i}`;

    let values = Object.values(data); // ['foo', 'bar']
    values.push(req.params.id);

    // .....
    // query = 'UPDATE foo SET  name=$1, password=$2 WHERE id=$3'
    // values = ['foo', 'bar', req.params.id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @vitaly-t! faster and cleaner, always a good result :)

for reference, i've also included the insert statement using the helpers as described above as well.

```
    //firstly create a function that skips the nulls for strings
function str(column) {
    return {
        name: column,
        skip: c => c.value === null || c.value === undefined || !c.exists
    };
}

//now a function that skips nulls for integers, while parsing type
function int(column) {
    return {
        name: column,
        skip: c => c.value === null || c.value === undefined || !c.exists,
        init: c => +c.value
    };
}

//creating a column set for all updates
var usefulColumSet = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    str('string1'), str('string2'), str('string3'), str('string4'), str('string5'),
    str('string6'), int('integer1'), int('integer2'), int('integer3'),
    str('date1'), str('date2'), str('date3'), int('currency1'), int('currency2')
], {table: 'generic1'});

//*********************CREATE a single record*************************
function createRecord(req, res, next) {
    var insert = pgp.helpers.insert(req.body, usefulColumSet);

    db.none(insert)
        .then(function(){
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'Inserted one record successully'
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            return next(err);
        });
}


//************************UPDATE a single record*************
function updateRecord(req, res, next) {
    var update = pgp.helpers.update(req.body, usefulColumSet) + ' WHERE id = ' + parseInt(req.params.id);

    db.none(update)
        .then(function() {
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 200,
                    message: 'updated a single record cleanly'
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Since you are not providing attribute `def` - default value when the property doesn't exist, you will end up with `c.value` equal `undefined` in those cases, so checking for `!c.exists` isn't needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript sample:

```
 async updateService(obj: T): Promise<void>{
        update(obj, table, getFields(obj));
   }
```

Generate the column set fields that you want to update only:

```
 private getFields(obj: T) {
    const fields: string[] = [];
    if (string1){
        fields.push('string1');
    }
    if (string2){
        fields.push('string2');
    }
    if (string3){
        fields.push('string3');
    }
    return fields;
   }
```

Define the PG method:

```
async update (object: T, table: string, fields: string[]) : Promise<void> {
        try {
            const columnSet = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(fields,{table: table});
            const where = pgp.as.format('WHERE id = $1', [object.id]);
            const update = `${pgp.helpers.update(object, columnSet)} ${where}`;
            await this.db.none(update);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('update: An error happened when trying to update: %s. Error: %s', JSON.stringify(object), e);
        }
    }
```

Find more details here: [pg-promise using named parameters in an UPDATE SET statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59517417/)

Comment: Added `await` that you forgot in front of `this.db.none`

Comment: Because otherwise it will create a loose promise. You also misquoted the very example the link to which you gave, which does use `await` there.