# Skip null values on Upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I am using pg-promise to handle my Postgres queries and I am having troubles finding a solution to the below query:

I am trying to create a single method for batch upserting many rows at once,
This is my code:

```
massUpsert: (orgId, entities) => db.tx((t) => {
    const queries = [];
    entities.forEach((entity) => {
      const { id, name, age, type } = entity;
      queries.push(
        t.one(`INSERT INTO public.table (id, name, age, type) 
             VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
              ON CONFLICT (id) DO update
                SET 
                 name = $2,
                 age = $3,
                 type = $4
              RETURNING *`,
        [id, name, age, type]));
    });
    return t.batch(queries);
}),
```

Now the problem is that in some cases I get null for one or more of the fields and I want the DB to remain with old values instead of replacing it with a null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought about using triggers on the database itself?

Comment: You shouldn't use within `ON CONFLICT` things like `name = $2`, it should be `name = excluded.name`, which you can further improve with a function checking against `null`.

Comment: @vitaly-t I did not fully understand you, what do you mean by using excluded.name?

Comment: That's the standard solution, and `excluded` is a reserved name, referring to the conflicting columns. Check PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: @vitaly-t, As far as I have to understand excluded does not answer to my need for the columns that are in conflict are not to be updated but the other columns, The only thing that I want to prevent is to ignore updating columns with a null value when updating.

Comment: @Ronco `name = COALESCE(excluded.name, name)` will do that. Also see my answer below + the links.

Comment: @Ronco didn't the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [helpers](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) methods for generating the query:

```js
const skipIfNull = name => ({name, skip: c => c.value === null});
    
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    '?id',
    skipIfNull('name'),
    skipIfNull('age'),
    skipIfNull('type')
], {table: 'table'});
```

See types [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) and [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html).

Generating the query from sample `data`:

```js
const data = {
    id: 1,
    name: null, // will be skipped
    age: 123,
    type: 'tt'
};
    
    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs) + ' ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ' +
        pgp.helpers.sets(data, cs) + ' RETURNING *';
```

will generate:

```sql
INSERT INTO "table"("id","name","age","type") VALUES(1,null,123,'tt')
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET "age"=123,"type"='tt' RETURNING *
```

**UPDATE:** Newer syntax via [assignColumns](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html#assignColumns) is better than the `sets` approach.

But beware that as per method [set](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.sets) API, it will return an empty string, if all your conditional columns turn out to be `null`, so the resulting query will be invalid. You will want to add a check for that ;)

Also, considering that you are generating a multi-insert, it is possible to generate just one multi-row insert that would offer better performance. For that see [Multi-row insert with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300997/multi-row-insert-with-pg-promise).

See also:

- [skip update columns with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697330/skip-update-columns-with-pg-promise)

Comment: The Solution worked, thank you for the quick answer. It is good to know that the library has an owner :)

Comment: Is there a way to use pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs), To generate a query that skips NULL values on inserting? The logic behind it is to use the default values that are set in the table because the fields consisting with NOT-NULL constraint.

Comment: I have tried using the above solutions but it still generates a query with inserting null on missing fields, 

see the example code here: https://gist.github.com/RoncoCo/70c07ff57375c83f77b18fbe6f0dab1e

Comment: @Ronco your definition of the optional column there doesn't follow the logic of what you are trying to do. See my answer there.

Comment: Is there a way to make the unique constraint on a combination of columns?

i.e - 

const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    '?(id, external_id)',
    skipIfNull('name'),
    skipIfNull('age'),
    skipIfNull('type')
], {table: 'table'});

So, in that case, the unique will be on id AND external_id

Comment: @Ronco Unique constraints are not part of INSERT or UPDATE queries. So I don't know what you are talking about. And if you want to add ON CONFLICT, just append one to the query.