# PG-Promise - "Property doesn't exist" error with skip function

Tags: pg-promise

I am having trouble figuring out how to utilize `skip` to skip undefined/null values. I keep getting `Error: Property 'vehicle_id' doesn't exist`. Is `skip` within column set and `skip` of `upsertReplaceQuery()` somehow conflicting with each other? How can I get it to work?

```js
const vehicleColumnSet = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
  [
    { name: 'user_id' },
    {
      name: 'vehicle_id',
      skip: (c) => !c.exists,
    },
    { name: 'model_id', def: null },
  ],
  { table: 'vehicle' }
);

const upsertReplaceQuery = (data, columnSet, conflictField) => {
  return `${pgp.helpers.insert(
    data,
    columnSet
  )} ON CONFLICT(${conflictField}) DO UPDATE SET ${columnSet.assignColumns({
    from: 'EXCLUDED',
    skip: conflictField,
  })}`;
};

const vehicleUpsertQuery = upsertReplaceQuery(
  {
    user_id,
    model_id: vehicle_model,
  },
  vehicleColumnSet,
  'user_id'
);

await task.none(vehicleUpsertQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has no support for any `skip` logic within its multi-row insert syntax.

[And pg-promise documentation also tells you](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) within `skip` description:

> An override for skipping columns dynamically.
> Used by methods `update` (for a single object) and `sets`, ignored by methods `insert` and `values`.
> It is also ignored when conditional flag `cnd` is set.

At most, you can add such logic against a single-row insert, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253866/skip-null-values-on-upsert).