# pg-promise using named parameters in an UPDATE SET statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I want to implement an UPDATE SET statement with named parameters? Is it possible?

For an object like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "new_name",
    password: "new_password",
    subscribed: true,
    email: "new_email@email.com"
}
```

This is my guess:

```
UPDATE
    accounts
SET
    $(this:name) = $(this:csv)
WHERE
    _id = $(this._id)
```

The object fields may vary depending on requests sent, so I don't want to "hard code" the parameters in.

Comment: Why would you guess like that? There's ton of examples on the library's website, like [Learn by Example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example). You update columns normally, by listing them via comma, according to PostgreSQL syntax. Using `this` isn't gonna do any magic for you here.

Comment: @vitaly-t I thought maybe there'd be some kind of built in loop that I may have missed. I know from the documentation that `this:csv` automatically converts it into a kind of `.join(",")` thing. I was also thinking about using a `select $(this:csv)` somehow with the update.

Comment: Each of those filters, `:name` and `:csv` do indeed provide some basic automation. But in case of a `SET` operation, you need a combination. So unless you opt for a [multi-row update approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119922/postgresql-multi-row-updates-in-node-js), you will have to use those columns explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to automate a `SET` operation within `pg-promise`, is if you start using the multi-row update approach, with [ColumnSet](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html)-s.

```js
// create column set statically, once:
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?_id', 'name', 'password', 'subscribed', 'email'],
                                     {table: 'accounts'});
```

When generating the update query...

```js
const where = pgp.as.format('WHERE _id = $1', [_id]);
const update = `${pgp.helpers.update(data, cs)} ${where}`;
```

Executing the query:

```js
await db.none(update);
```

Comment: I'm currently not with my code but do you think something like this would work? `UPDATE accounts SET ($(this:name)) = (SELECT $(this:csv);`

Comment: It might, if you try. But it's a different type of query altogether, from the one you asked.

Comment: I would welcome such a feature too, as the OP asked, something like `... SET ${this:combine} WHERE ...` and it could generate the comma separated pairs like `name1 = value1, name2 = value2,..` based on the json object provided for the statement.

Comment: @Zavael You can generate assignments, using [helpers.sets](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.sets).

Comment: yes, but I forgot to mention I am using external sql scripts as is suggested in your [QueryFile](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/QueryFile.html), but now I am tempted to replace all the scripts with this helper one/two liners :)

Comment: @Zavael You can use both, SQL files and variables in them that are generated SQL. It is quite normal mixed approach.